# Using Python to calculate the unique conic section using five points

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, linear-algebra

I'm trying to develop a Python code which can tell you the centre, directrix, foci and the equation of any unique conic section using a set of five-point inputs from the user.

I'm currently running the code with Python2 on Sublime Text on a MacBook which I've installed Scipy , Numpy and Sympy.

### After the user have input the five points, there will be five different general formula of conic sections which has a standard form of:

### ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey +f = 0

Then after solving a,b,c,d,e,f individually, we would have a formula looking something like x^2 - y = 0, this would be the equation for that unique conic section.

I'm using LUsolve, however no matter what I input, the results it gives me is always [0,0,0,0,0,0]. Please look at my code and help me w/ this, thanks.

```
enter code here

import numpy as np
import scipy

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        rep = '(' + str(self.x) + ', ' + str(self.y) + ')'
        return rep

class Conic:                                                
    def __init__(self, points):                             
        self.points = points                                

    def equation(self):                                     # ...                               
        from sympy import symbols
        from sympy import Matrix, ImmutableMatrix
        from sympy.matrices import zeros
        from sympy.solvers import solve, nsolve, solveset
        x, y, z, v = symbols("x y z v")
        # you need symbols for x and y
        a, b, c, d , e, f = symbols('a b c d e f')
        xs = Matrix([a, b, c, d, e, f])
        l = [[x ** 2, x*y, y ** 2, x, y, 1]]
        #l = []

        for point in self.points: 
            l.append([point.x ** 2, point.x * point.y, point.y ** 2, point.x, point.y, 1])

        m = Matrix(l)
        v = m.det()

        soln = m.LUsolve(zeros(6, 1)) ###from scipy
        print(soln)
        return None

    def __str__(self):
    pass
    return None


from random import randint
points = [Point(-2, 4),
          Point(-1, 1),
          Point(0, 0),
          Point(1, 1),
          Point(2, 4)]
for point in points:
    print(point)
c = Conic(points)
c.equation()
```

And result is here:

```
(-2, 4)
(-1, 1)
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 4)
Matrix([[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]])

***Repl Closed***
```

Comment: I see your edit but it is not yet clear for me - what is  `soln = m.LUsolve` intended for?

Comment: Why do you need Sympy for a numerical solution?

Comment: @AhmedFasih Because I've tried every equation solving function from Scipy, Numpy and Sympy, so I left the importation there although I'm not using any function from it.

Comment: Hey did any of the answers help you find a solution? If so, can you accept one of them? Or can you post your own answer so we can close this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you’re getting zeros is because you’re solving the linear system with `zeros(6,1)`, in which case the all-zero solution is valid. Try setting the right-hand-side to something non-zero.

The other issue is, with five points and six unknowns, the solution is underdetermined. But you can fix the last coordinate to some arbitrary value and solve for that.

Here’s my Numpy purely-numerical solution:

```
import numpy as np


def fivePointsToConic(points, f=1.0):
    """Solve for the coefficients of a conic given five points in Numpy array

    `points` should have at least five rows.

    `f` is the constant that you can specify. With the returned solution,
    `(a, b, c, d, e, f)`, the full conic is specified as:

    $a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 + d x + e y = -f$

    If `points` has exactly five rows, the equation will be exact. If `points`
    has *more* than five rows, the solution will be a least-squares one that
    fits the data the best.
    """
    from numpy.linalg import lstsq

    x = points[:, 0]
    y = points[:, 1]
    if max(x.shape) < 5:
        raise ValueError('Need >= 5 points to solve for conic section')

    A = np.vstack([x**2, x * y, y**2, x, y]).T
    fullSolution = lstsq(A, f * np.ones(x.size))
    (a, b, c, d, e) = fullSolution[0]
    return (a, b, c, d, e, f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    points = np.array([[-2, 4.], [-1., 1], [0., 0], [1., 1], [2., 4]])
    print(fivePointsToConic(points))
```

Evaluating this in the Python REPL or running it as a script prints out the following solution to your problem, assuming `f = 1` (using the notation `a` through `f` on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic#Dimension_counting)):

```
(0.62499999999999989, 9.7144514654701197e-17, -0.24999999999999983, -2.9598635688993528e-16, 0.62499999999999989, 1.0)
```

Or roughly `[0.625, 0, -0.25, 0, 0.625, 1]`. Does that match what you expected?

Comment: 'I think the reason you’re getting zeros is because you’re solving the linear system with zeros(6,1), in which case the all-zero solution is valid. Try setting the right-hand-side to something non-zero.' What do you mean by the 'Right-hand-side'? Thanks

Comment: When solving a linear system via least-squares, you solve `A . x = b` for some unknown `x`. In this case, `b` is the “right-hand side”. In my code, this equation is solved for via `lstsq(A, f * np.ones(x.size))`. See, I took `b` (right-hand side) to be `f * np.ones(...)`, *not* `zeros`.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt what are you trying to reach. Your first goal is to build equation of ellipse from five points. So you can use Braikenridge-Maclaurin Construction ([formula 8 here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicSection.html))

[image]

where the first row is **symbolic** but other rows are **values**. I don't know how SymPy works and cannot say whether your `l` matrix is correct and why you solve it as `[L]=[0]` equation system.

Without SymPy - to get a  formula, one can find coefficients through minors of the whole [determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) (Laplace formula with the first row elements).

So coefficient c, for example, is value of minor for the third element (don't forget to change sign for b,d,f).

```
    |x1^2 x1*y1 x1 y1 1|
    |..................|                   
c = |..................|                   
    |..................|                   
    |x5^2 x5*y5 x5 y5 1|
```

I suspect that Scipy or Numpy might contain methods for extraction of minors